# dustjs: should async calls ever be made from a template helper?

Tags: node.js, express, dust.js, kraken.js

Looking for some thoughts and feedback on making async requests from dust.js template helpers:

Dust.js can make async requests from template helpers, but is it actually a good idea to make use of them? Consider this scenario...

A particular page requires several api requests to be rendered. In the page's route controller, a single async api request gets the bulk of the data for the page and passes the data to the template to be rendered. In the template there are several reusable and standalone dust helpers (can be dropped in on any page) that make their own async requests in order to display their components.

In this situation, all the dust helpers have to wait until the request made from the controller finishes before their calls can be made (when template rendering begins).

It seems that ideally (excluding having one endpoint for all data on the page) all requests should occur in the route controller in order to avoid synchronous calls, otherwise the request chain would be 1) controller requests 2) dust helper requests 3) nested/dependent dust helper requests.

Cons:

- route controller complexity by calling n services to build the view model
- adding display components to new pages require changes to controller and template instead of just adding a template helper

Pros:

- reduce/eliminate synchronous requests and increase performance
- easier to understand the view model

What are your thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider to use your templates only server side I would move everything into the controller. I like to have a controller who "controls" all the data needed for the view layer.

If you think about using dust templates in the browser (so ajax calls from the cleint) both ways in my point of view are reasonable from an architectural view. 
But I would ask my self some question about user experience before deciding:

1. How much time would take to complete all the calls from the
   controller? Sometimes is better to send partial data to the user and
   give to him something to view and load other components later for a
   better user experience. But if the overhead is not over some ms, I
   would decide to build my page context all in the controller.
2. Where is the data displayed in the page? Do you need it in the first
   part of the page? Or user should scroll to view other sets of data? 
   If the data is not consumed immediately I would decide to leave it
   to the client.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Client rendering is a great reason not to make all the calls from the controller and load content on demand. With regards to the implementation I'm working on, our in-network API calls are quite fast (even uncached) so it's not a problem at the moment to have the controller handle all the async.  As we add new complexity and features going forward we really should be considering loading more content from the client, although indexable SEO content is imperative for us so we'd need a robust solution for that.